# Вызов функции в питон3

Tags: python, функции

У меня есть такая конструкция в коде:

```
class Programm(Frame):
    def calculation(self):
        def one():
            ...
        def two():
            ...
```

Далее внутри класса, но за пределами функции calculation я хочу получить вывод функции one.
примерно вот так:

```
def call():
     one()
```

Как это сделать и возможно ли это вообще?

Comment: А зачем вы сделали в данном случае замыкание? Это точно то, что вы хотите?

Comment: Не совсем понимаю что такое замыкание, но в коде других вариантов нету. Надо получить вывод этой функции. Пробовал еще что-то вроде def call(): calculation().one(), но не получается

Comment: имеется в виду - зачем вы внутрь одной функции запихнули другую функцию - для чего?

Comment: Ну вот я вас и спросил, зачем вы это сделали. Судя по всему вам это не нужно, и вы можете вынести функции `one()` и другие в класс, таким образом вы сможете их вызвать `Programm().one()`

Answer (score 4):

какой-то у вас извращённый код

но раз уж начали извращаться - можно так:

```
class A:
    def method1(self):
        def func1():
            return 1
        def func2():
            return 2
        return (func1, func2)

    def method2(self):
        return self.method1()[0]()


value = A()

print(value.method2())
```

Но почему не сделать все функции методами класса?

```
class A:
    def func1(self):
        return 1

    def func2(self):
        return 2

    def method1(self):
        return 3

    def method2(self):
        return self.func1()


value = A()

print(value.method2())
```

Если же вам надо, чтобы снаружи нельзя было вызвать некоторые методы - сделайте их приватными (используя двойное подчеркивание перед названием метода):

```
class A:
    def __func1(self):
        return 1

    def func2(self):
        return 2

    def method1(self):
        return 3

    def method2(self):
        return self.__func1()


value = A()

print(value.__func1()) # тут будет ошибка
print(value.method2()) # тут все будет хорошо работать
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте просто использовать оператор global.

```
class Programm:
    def calculation(self):
        def one():
            print(1)
        def two():
            print(2)

        global one, two

def call():
    one()
        
call()

# Вывод - 1
```

однако это плохая практика, лучше так вообще не делать

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
class Programm():
    def calculation(self, val=None):
        def one():
            print('\tdef one():')
            
        def two():
            print('\tdef two():')
            
        if val == "one":
            one()
        elif val == "two":
            two()
            
    def call(self, val=None):
        self.calculation(val)

        
p = Programm()
print('\nВызываем -> p.call()')
p.call()
print('\nВызываем -> p.call("one")')
p.call("one")
print('\nВызываем -> p.call("one")')
p.call("two")
```